# Is this a secure implementation of a basic HMAC authentication system for my REST API?

Tags: api, rest, hash, restful-authentication, hmac

I'm building a very basic REST API for my site. The only verb I'm using at the moment is GET which simply outputs a list of posts on my site.

For authentication, I have been reading about HMAC and in particular this article:

http://websec.io/2013/02/14/API-Authentication-Public-Private-Hashes.html

My question centres around what the 'hashed content' should be. As I am not posting any data to the API, I have just been hashing my public key (with a simple salt) using my private key.

Is this a secure method or should I use a different 'content hash'? The data is not sensitive in any way - this was just a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to consider the "replay attacker". When the attacker captures a packet between your API client and the server, what damage can she do when she replays it later?

In your case, if you only use the API key of the user in the HMAC, then the attacker will be able to impersonate that user when she replay the requests. She can call any API request and just set the HMAC to what she captured, as it will validate.

If none of the parameters of the request are included, the attacker will be able to call the request and specify her own parameters. So it's better if the parameters are also included in the HMAC. It doesn't prevent replay of the request with these specific parameters though.

You can include a timestamp parameter to the request and in the HMAC. The server will recompute the HMAC including the timestamp passed in, and it will also verify that the timestamp is recent enough. As the attacker cannot forge new HMAC out of thin air, she will only be able to use ones with matching timestamps that you will reject based on age.